A series of approximations to $\pi$
Let $a_0=2 \sqrt{3}$ and $b_0=3$, and define two sequences recursively by
$$
a_n=\frac{2 a_{n-1} \cdot b_{n-1}}{a_{n-1}+b_{n-1}}
$$
and
$$
b_n=\sqrt{a_n \cdot b_{n-1}} \cdot
$$
Prove that $\left(a_n\right)$ is monotonically decreasing and is convergent, and prove that $\left(b_n\right)$ is monotonically increasing and convergent. Then prove that they convers
Remark:
This is a classical recurrence, and the monotonicity of $a_n$ and $b_n$ is obvious, but my puzzle is, how does it approximate irrational numbers $\pi$ ? Further, if the initial values $a_0$ and $b_0$ are any two numbers greater than and less than $\pi$, they obviously converge to $\pi$, but why? I have no effective means to deal with this problem, I also tried to find the relevant limit definition of $\pi$, but obviously I failed.

Can't you try to solve $a_{n+1}=a_n$ and $b_{n+1}=b_n$?

This looks similar to the  Geometric–harmonic mean

@MartinR: why does it go to $\pi$? If you just alter the starting points, you get another limit value.

@Dominique: I am not aware of a “simple” explanation. The geometric-harmonic mean is related to the arithmetic-geometric mean, and that can be computed as an elliptic integral.

@MartinR: I'm just wondering which function has this as a result: $f(2 \sqrt{3}, 3)=\pi$ and how this ±simple iteration leads to this function.

"prove that they convers" -> "prove that they converge to the same number"?

@MartinR similar but distinct: note that $b_n=\sqrt{a_{\color{red}n}\cdot b_{n-1}}$

@MartinR：Thank you very much.I have understood the relevant background for a while. My initial comment was indeed weong, and the initial value was not arbitrarily given.

@aschepler:Sorry,this should be corrected for them to converge to the same numeric $\pi$

@Lily You can click "Edit" under your question to fix that.
